# Area between two circles

Tags: geometry, circles

Let there be two circles of radius a and b such that b is greater than a. The area between the two circles would be : π(b²-a²). But why isn't it π(b-a)². Obviously I am looking for a more mature answer supported with a rigorous proof if any. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot take the area between the two circles to be $\pi (b-a)^2$ since doing so will give you the area of a circle with radius $b-a$ which is not what you are looking for. Imagine calculating the area of the figure left over after removing the smaller circle from the bigger one and then on the other side calculating area of a circle with a radius equal the the thickness of the leftover figure mentioned before. both areas will appear to diverge as the two circles get bigger with their differences in radii getting smaller which clearly says that they both will not be equal.

Answer (score 0):

The area of the big circle is $\pi b^2$.

The area of the small circle is $\pi a^2$.

Now subtract the two : $\pi b^2-\pi a^2 = \pi (b^2-a^2)$.

Note that $\pi (b-a)^2=\pi(b^2-2ab+a^2)$ which is not the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, i know this but why exactly is the latter one wrong. I have two circles I take the difference of their radii and find the area of resulting circle. Why is this different from directly subtracting their areas.

Comment: I'm not sure what more can be said. It is not true to directly subtract the radios because it is simply not true.

Answer (score 0):

The radius does *not* get smaller, that is what you say when you use $b-a$. But the area of the circle is given by $\pi a^2$ and $\pi b^2$ and the difference gives:

$$\pi b^2-\pi a^2=\pi(b^2-a^2)$$

Comment: The question still persist. Why is π(b-a)² wrong

Comment: @NikhilSaxena Well, $\pi(b - a)^2$ is wrong for the same reason that $a^b \pi$ is wrong: it's because it's not equal to the correct answer (in general). Is there a particular reason why you believe it might be $\pi(b - a)^2$?

Comment: @user793679 - I know it is wrong but I don't know why. Don't you think there should be an argument/statement that tells why it is wrong other than telling thats the way it has been. As for why I care is because it doesn't has to be wrong.

Comment: @NikhilSaxena as I wrote in my answer, when you use $b-a$ that means that the radius of the resulting circle is equal to $b-a$ which is not right.